# Filter by date from SQL Text Field

Tags: php, sql, datetime

i've run into the following problem:

I had to migrate a database from MS SQL Server where some fields contained date values that weren't stored as such. For example there was a field "offers" with an "validfrom" and "validto" field. Sadly, they used text fields (varchar) for that type of input and im having a  hard time now to filter it properly by date. An example as follows :

```
datefrom = "21.01.2012"
dateto = "21.05.2012"
```

Now im trying to sort out the old entries by date using

```
$curDate = date('d.m.Y'); // Outputs 19.03.2013
```

in my PHP PDO i use the following query

```
$query = "SELECT * from mytable where validtill >= '$curDate'"
```

which would output

```
$query = "SELECT * from mytable where validtill >= '19.03.2013'"
```

still i am getting old entries with date entries from 2011. I think i am missing something - maybe i cant compare strings as "date". I tried changing the field from vharchar to date but when i do, the whole imported data gets messed up.

Any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: Which RDBMS are you now using, MySQL?

Comment: In the SQL part, I believe you can do a CAST to Varchar the column validtill, and do not forget to format the output to the YYYYMMDD, then you can compare it to the string you are trying to (of course, the string must be in YYYYMMDD format also).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your question, you say you had to migrate from MS Sql Server -- what database did you migrate to?  You need to convert the varchar field to a date to do a date comparison.

Assuming MySQL, then you could use `str_to_date`.  Something like this should work:

```
select str_to_date(dtfield, '%d.%m.%Y')
from yourtable
where str_to_date(dtfield, '%d.%m.%Y') > str_to_date('1/20/2012', '%m/%d/%Y')
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2ff3/1)

Assuming you're still in SQL Server, then you'd have to strip out each part of the date to put the date in a format SQL Server understands and then use `CONVERT` to change its datatype to a date:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,RIGHT(dtfield,4)+SUBSTRING(dtfield,4,2)+LEFT(dtfield,2))
FROM yourtable
WHERE CONVERT(datetime,RIGHT(dtfield,4)+SUBSTRING(dtfield,4,2)+LEFT(dtfield,2)) > '1/20/2012'
```

[More Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/12f99/1)

Comment: I have migrated to MySQL. I tried your advice and it worked perfectly. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Right. That will do a string comparison and seems like you have the DAY first. Which means march 21, 2013 is greater than march 19, 2014... because the first thing it compares to sort is the day.

This text string comparison would work if you could rearrange the data to Y.m.d, that way 2013 > 2012 > 2011, and 2013-02-xx > 2012-02-xx...

My advice would be to make a new column in your database, and you can use a PHP script to convert and store the new correct values as dates.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that:

```
$query = "SELECT CAST(m.field as date) as field, m.* from mytable as m where m.field >='" . date('Y-m-d') . "';";
```